# How to use single print function to print multiple lines?

Tags: python-3.x

I just started learning Python3 and I got to the part where I started using arithmetic operations, I am trying to break the result into multiple lines, I used sep='/n' and /n, but I gives this error (positional argument follows keyword argument) I know it maybe a noob question but I can't figure out how to do it or what to search for in Google.

```
x=22
y=18
print('x+y=', x+y, 'x-y=', x-y)
```

The result I get is this:
x+y= 40 x-y= 4.

I want it to be displayed like this:

x+y= 40

x-y= 4

Comment: You should add the optional argument `sep` AFTER all other arguments. But you will then have a newline between EACH parameter which is obviously not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
x=22
y=18
print('x+y =', x+y, '\nx-y =', x-y)
```

or (better IMHO):

```
x=22
y=18
print('x+y = %d\nx-y = %d' % (x+y, x-y))
```

(the latter using formatting features).

Comment: Thank you, I used /n instead of \n before and I used it like this print('x+y =', x+y, /n, 'x-y =', x-y) , so I got those errors, thanks again. It haven't still reached to using formatting so I'll use the '\n' feature.

Comment: Hi, I need another help on the topic, I want to display the names of people  and their ages so I used the code like this.                                                 x='Steve'
y='Sam'
x1=24
y1=22
print(x, x1,'\n',y, y1)
                                                                                     The result I get is this:                                                       Steve 24                                                                              Sam 22. But the Sam in the next line displays with a space from left. How do I remove the space?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [**format**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead:

```
x=22
y=18
print("x+y= {}\nx-y= {}".format(x+y, x-y))
```

**Output:**

```
x+y= 40
x-y= 4
```

Comment: So it's the same as this 
print('x+y = %d\nx-y = %d' % (x+y, x-y)) , but you used {}, I don't know in what situation {} are used but I'll remember to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Method 0: Use multiple print statements

```
print('x+y=', x+y)
print('x-y=', x-y)
```

Method 1: Add `\n` when you want to end the line.

```
print('\nx+y=', x+y, '\nx-y=', x-y,end='') # end='' just to take total control of when to keep new line
```

Method 2: keep everything you want to print in a line in single argument

```
print('x+y=%d'%(x+y),'x-y=%d'(x-y),sep='\n')
```

You can look at the help for print function :`help(print)`